# Поиск по бд

Tags: поиск, php, mysql

как реализовать поиск как в Лиге17: http://league17.ru/pokedex.php?sp_id=235

Пример:

1.вводим "s" нам показывает список покемонов у кого в название есть буква "s"

2.Вводим 1 нас переадресует в  http://league17.ru/pokedex.php?sp_id=1

1. Если ничего не найдено пишет "Покемон по вашему запросу не найден."

Answer (score 1):

запрос будет выглядеть примерно так

```
select * from table where name like %"s"%
```

Вот [не плохая статья](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mysql_search) Безопасный и удобный поиск в mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Юзайте [LIKE](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_comparison_functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

офф топ) Но я бы так не делал) Оставте поиск по названию с помощью оператора LIKE. 
Почему я бы не делал как они:

1. введите 1000 в поиск - и вы увидете покемона под номером 001 - это не совсем верно.
2. А вдруг в имени покемона будет цифра? то вы его так не найдете(